# MySQL wrapper for ios

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, database

I am working on my first iOS-application and I want to use MySQL as my remote database.

I've been googing around and reading here at Stack, but I can't find my `new` answers to the question. Does there exists any good wrappers out there? I found this link: [mysql for ios](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/), but it clearly states that it is not guaranteed to be accepted in the App Store.

I really want to have a wrapper rather than using some sort of webservice.

Anyone have some more updated news on this?

Comment: Currenttly No. Either use CoreData or sqlite . MySQL is too heavy for mobile

Comment: @MalcolmMashmallow: Not sure if I understand 100% correctly, but I want to connect to a remote database. Does it really matter if this is done in sqlite or MySQL?

Comment: OK I understand what you mean. You can use REST method for webservice. It's easy to setup using PHP MVC (open source library available:-CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Symphony), C# MVC . I think you are worrying about using SOAP method? Which method you are currently using?

Comment: @MalcolmMashmallow: as I wrote; I don't want to use a webservice, because I want to be able to execute the queries directly in object-c, like: `MySQL sql = new MySQL()` and `sql.connect('foobar');`. I have not started to code yet, so this is just for research. Please excuse my none-objective-c syntax.

Comment: use REST then. This will enlightening you [Simple Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)

Comment: With REST you can query and get your data in XML/JSON/plain text. Usually I pass the encrypted one (of course). I also use SOAP method sometimes but I prefer REST more because it's lightweight. The library I recommend for iOS to handle networking is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use SQLite or CoreData libraries, they are very low overhead. CoreData is built into iOS functionality, SQLite just needs the .db file and a library (part of iOS) imported.

If you could somehow get your MySQL database online and expose it via REST you could possibly use REST to get and set data into and out of the database. But this will slow your app to a crawl.

CoreData is fast, and when using the data in context like that, it simplifies everything. Writing SQL statements is slowly becoming an archaic process.